# Не работает вертикальный скролл в flex

Tags: html, css

Делаю чатик, функционал уже готов, только вот не получилось сделать вертикальный скролл...
Сам скролл я добавил `overflow-y: scroll` а вот сообщения всё равно не скроллят.
Когда я убираю `display: flex` скролл начинает работать, только всё из-за этого начинает ехать...

```css
/* Chat body */

.chat-body_messages {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chat-body_message-time {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.chat-body_message-in {
  align-self: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.chat-body_message-in>.chat-body_message-text {
  background-color: #8106A9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.chat-body_message-out {
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.chat-body_message-out>.chat-body_message-text {
  background-color: #3C9DD0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-body">
  <div class="chat-body_messages" id="messages">
    <span class="chat-body_message-out">
                    <span class="chat-body_message-time">17:53</span>
    <span class="chat-body_message-text">Привет</span>
    </span>
    <span class="chat-body_message-in">
                    <span class="chat-body_message-text">Привет</span>
    <span class="chat-body_message-time">17:53</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логику поведения не понял, но решить удалось следующими действиями:

1. элементу `#messages` (родителю "сообщений") задаём `min-height: 100%`, а не `height`, ну и убираем от него `overflow`.
2. А вот родителю `#messages` (`.chat-body`, а лучше создать "элемент обёртку") выдаём уже ограничение по высоте (если надо) и `overflow-y: scroll`

```js
let a = 0, b = 0,
    timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
      if(b >= 1) a = a == 0 ? 1 : 0;
      
      $('#messages').append(`<span class="chat-body_message-${a == 0 ? 'out' : 'in'}">
      <span class="chat-body_message-time">17:53</span>
      <span class="chat-body_message-text">Привет</span>
    </span>`);
      
      if(b <= 50) {
        b++;
        timerId = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
      } else clearTimeout(timerId);
    }, 1000);
```

```css
/* Chat body */

.chat-body {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden auto;
}

.chat-body_messages {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.chat-body_message-time {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.chat-body_message-in {
  align-self: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.chat-body_message-in>.chat-body_message-text {
  background-color: #8106A9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.chat-body_message-out {
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.chat-body_message-out>.chat-body_message-text {
  background-color: #3C9DD0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat-body">
  <div class="chat-body_messages" id="messages">
    <span class="chat-body_message-out">
      <span class="chat-body_message-time">17:53</span>
      <span class="chat-body_message-text">Привет</span>
    </span>
    <span class="chat-body_message-in">
      <span class="chat-body_message-text">Привет</span>
      <span class="chat-body_message-time">17:53</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```